# How do I sort an array of objects by id when the id has letters at the beginning?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects where I need to sort them based on id, my id is always in this format: XX456

Example of array I need to sort:

```
let arr = [{ id: XX123, something: 'etc' }
         , { id: XX225, something: 'etc1' }
         , { id: XX324, something: 'etc2' }]
```

I need to have my array with the lowest number at the top going down, so I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    a['id'].replace(/[A-Z]/g, '');
    b['id'].replace(/[A-Z]/g, '');

    return a['id'] - b['id'];
});
```

I am unsure of how to proceed as I don't know how else to sort with a string in front or how to ignore it differently, any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `+a.id.slice(2) - +b.id.slice(2)`?

Comment: Strings are immutable. And as the [documentation for `.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should have already told you; _"The `replace()` method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement."_

Comment: @evolutionxbox It worked! thanks so much, post as an answer so I can credit you :)

Comment: You haven't assigned the replaced string to anything.. `replace()` returns  a replaced string.

Comment: @mynameismyname1010101 added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for regex. The ID's can be cast to numbers, after slicing off the first two characters.

```js
let arr = [{
  id: 'XX326',
  something: 'etc2'
}, {
  id: 'XX123',
  something: 'etc'
}, {
  id: 'XX225',
  something: 'etc1'
}, {
  id: 'XX324',
  something: 'etc2'
}];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.id.slice(2) - b.id.slice(2);
});

console.log(arr);
```

And `.slice` ["extracts a section of the string and returns it as a new one"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically very similar to evolutionxbox's answer but it differs in that I used `String.protitype.substr()` instead of `String.prototype.slice()` and that I skipped the first unary `+` Operator. (He removed it from his answer too ;-)).

```js
const arr = [{ id: "XX123", something: "etc" }, { id: "XX225", something: "etc1" }, { id: "XX324", something: "etc2" }, { id: "XX17", something: "etc1" }];

console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=>a.id.substr(2)-b.id.substr(2)))
```

Comment: How is _"Sorry, I was a bit late with my reply - evolutionxbox has already posted a valid reply!"_ in any way relevant for the question or the answer?

Comment: :D @Andreas, I apologize for the rough tone you met here with your comment. I only quickly added the sentence you criticized to my response when I realized that I was overtaken by evolutionxbox. I have no problem deleting my answer, as it does not really add much wisdom to this question anymore. ;-)

Comment: @cars10m your answer is valid, just remove the unnecessary remark and maybe replace it with a short explanation of how/why it works.

Comment: Just flag the comment as rude/harassment and move on. It's not worth the time to act on those pleasantries. If OP thinks this is good manner he will sooner or later get the bill for it.